# Determining the uid of a message appended to a mailbox via IMAP

Tags: imap

How do I determine the UID of a message which is added via `APPEND` to a mailbox? Through `STATUS` I can get a prediction of the next value beforehand and I can `SEARCH` afterwards, but relying on these introduces a race condition as other messages might have been added between these commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you IMAP server supports UIDPLUS, you will always get an `APPENDUID` response. This will contain the UID and the validity period for the UID.

Sample syntax from [RFC 4315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4315):

```
S: A003 OK [APPENDUID 38505 3955] APPEND completed
```

If your mailserver doesnt support `UIDPLUS`, you will have to do a `FETCH` for the UID, once your append operation is finished. If you are sure that no message was added after the append, go look for the last message in the `FETCH` response.

```
FETCH 1:* (UID)
```

If you are worried about other messages getting added, you can save an IMAP header like Message-ID before the `APPEND` and later use it in the `FETCH` operation.